# Swift Vapor: remove database field via migration and from struct at the same time

Tags: swift, database-migration, vapor

I have added a database migration to remove a field:

```swift
static func prepare(on conn: PostgreSQLConnection) -> EventLoopFuture<Void> {
    return Database.update(User.self, on: conn) { builder in
        builder.deleteField(for: \.name)
    }
}
```

Now this works fine except that when I remove the field `name` from my `User` struct, this doesn't compile anymore, because obviously, the keypath for `name` can't be found.
So this requires me to leave the field in the `User` struct until after the migration has run and then I can delete the field but then I also need to delete the migration.

That doesn't feel like a good practice to me and I'm probably doing something wrong here.
What can I do instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is get the field by name and have it remove that:

```
builder.deleteField(User.Database.QueryField.column("users", "name"))
```

where

- `users` is the table name
- `name` is the column/field name

Answer (score 1):

This is a complete migration showing a field added and then the revert to remove it:

```swift
    struct UpdateUserTable1: Migration {
        func prepare(on database: Database) -> EventLoopFuture<Void> {
            database.schema("User")
                .field("nextAttemptAt", .datetime)
                .update()
        }

        func revert(on database: Database) -> EventLoopFuture<Void> {
            database.schema("User")
                .deleteField("nextAttemptAt")
                .update()
        }
    }
```

As you can see, the migration doesn't require the field to be defined in the Model or not at any stage. This is the correct way to do it using Fluent.